# Access 2013 - Collecting Data via forms

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have read that the "Collect Data" feature is not available in Access 2013.

I am looking for another alternative to collect data from all of our branches without needing to physically capture each individual record.

I have considered the branches completing an excel spreadsheet containing the necessary data, and then importing it into access table when I receive it, however this process seems tedious, and may result in errors if the branches change the formatting of my excel template.

Is it perhaps possible to somehow create a form which can be emailed to staff members for data collection without the actual collect data functionality?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Create the Access database application and share with branches**

- Create two access database with the fornend(form) and backend(tables).
- Linked table from backend db to frontend db.
- Create a form on the frontend DB.
- locate fornend(form) and backend(tables) on share folder.
- share fornend(form) DB between branches for data collection.

Answer (score -1):

This might work in Access 2013 because 2013 can process Data Collection, but not create new forms(no wizard). But, VBA is VBA. Use code to change tables the same way the wizard would and create HTML emails, and you are in business!

Automate data collection forms using VBA
http://www.365advisor.com/ArticleContent0117aa79504211ba

This person seems to have figured out the VBA for an earlier version.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.access/NEyGBhf9MpI